# EasyRTC multi-connection with different network connection

Tags: webrtc, easyrtc

`EasyRTC` is a open source `webRTC` plugin used for many purpose.

My intention is to prepare a video chatting example using this. When I try this with same network connection (same wifi) it works like a charm, but when I try this with different wifi network its not working instead its through errors like

No usable `STUN/TURN` path -- in client end
undefined -- in initiator end.

Is there is any configuration I need to change to make this working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: While creating new RTCpeerconnection make sure you're passing 
STUN server like below `new RTCPeerConnection({"iceServers": [ {url:"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"} ] });`

Comment: I had modified the code still the same issue. [link](http://xucorelms.com:8081/demos/demo_multiparty.html) please check this link for testing

Comment: Hi, I believe you have added iceServers in getStats. Plz revert you code and try adding under
`function processIceConfig(iceConfig) { pc_config = {iceServers: [{url:"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]};`
this function `processIceConfig` actually gathers the iceServer info

Comment: Hi, I have tried that too.
already there are 4 different iceServers are coming as default such as
stun:stun.i.google.com:19302
stun:stun.sipgate.net
stun:217.10.68.152
stun:styn.sipgate.net

and new error message is coming as "Message rejected. Target easyrtcid is invalid, not using same application, or no longer online." 

for your information I am using easyrtc v.1.0.15 -- Dinesh

Comment: You may need to use a TURN server/service as well.  The TURN protocol can punch holes through firewalls and complex network setups where STUN can't get through.

Answer (score 1):

Mtbikemike has called it.
The general experiment is trying using the demos at demo.easyrtc.com. They are backed by a turn server. If they work across networks and your own doesn't, then it's probably a challenging network that needs a turn server. Turn servers don't punch holes so much as they act as packet relays.

Answer (score 0):

EasyRTC is an open source bundle of a signalling server, a Javascript client and some demonstration code, rather than a plugin. If you've got a firewall between you and the other party then you'll need a TURN server. We do have a TURN server backing the demo.easyrtc.com demos on our servers. We are working on putting together a paid TURN service specifically designed for EasyRTC. Should be available in the next month or so. For now you could look into using a TURN service from Xirsys or put up you own TURN server in the cloud or on your premise but outside the firewall.